# Assigning ids and names for all the input elements of the table row?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table row in html with 3 input fields as below.

```
 <tr class="prototype">
<td>
      <input id="" type="text" value="" name="">
</td>
<td>
     <input id="" type="text" value="" name="">
</td>
<td>
     <input id="" type="text" value="" name="">
</td>

    </tr>
```

Now i am cloning this row and trying to assign ids and names for the newly created row.

How can i assign ids and names for the newly created row.

I am cloning the row as below.

```
        var master = $("table.myTable");
    var prot = master.find("tr.prototype").clone();
    prot.removeClass('prototype');
    prot.addClass("someClass");

         // for all inputs of prot row i need to assign unique ids and names.

    jQuery('table.myTable tr:last').before(prot);
```

How can i get input elements of newly created row and assign ids and names before/after adding the row to table?

Thanks!

Comment: What are the IDs supposed to be?

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. You can't put `input` right after `tr`. There have to be a `td` or a `th`.

Comment: I need to assign unique ids and names for all the inputs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(".someClass").children('input').each(function(index){
   $(this).attr('id',$(this).attr('id')+index);
   $(this).attr('name',$(this).attr('name')+index);
})
```

The code just appends an index to the original id and name of the inputs.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Here i can have many rows with same class someClass. can i use as $(prot).children('input').each(function(index){
   $(this).attr('id',$(this).attr('id')+index);
   $(this).attr('name',$(this).attr('name')+index);
})

Comment: you can use prot.children('input') and so on

Answer (score 1):

Add a class to each of the three inputs and add attributes like this:

```
prot.find('.your_class_for_input_1').attr('name', 'your_new_name').attr('id', 'your_new_id');
prot.find('.your_class_for_input_2').attr('name', 'your_new_name').attr('id', 'your_new_id');
prot.find('.your_class_for_input_3').attr('name', 'your_new_name').attr('id', 'your_new_id');
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$(selector).attr('id', name)` to assign a new ID, and you can use `$(selector).attr('name', id)` to assign a new name.